# Show total sales per author in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using wordpress and woocommerce on a site where I have users create accounts so that they can upload their own clothing designs, I then sell these products and for each sale of their design the specific user gets a cut of the sale. I am trying to show the number of sales for each user on my site but can't figure out how to. I just need to be able to call the products created by each user specifically and then get the total sales from each of those products, then combine them into a total sales number for each individual user... can anyone point me in the right direction??

I am able to get the total sales for a single product using the

`<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'total_sales', true); ?>`

but I have no idea how to get it for a specific for a user.

Answer (score 1):

`<?php echo wc_get_customer_total_spent($user_id); ?>`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this flow:

1. Put author support on product post type
2. Get all products posted from that author
3. Get total sales for all listed product (refer point 2)

Hope this will be useful. :D